# How can I benchmark the resources used by GETTEXT for language support in PHP?

Tags: php, performance, benchmarking, gettext

Not long ago I was playing around with GETEXT in PHP for language files and doing a lot of research on the best way to offer multilingual support in a PHP app, it seems the general  consensus was to use GETEXT instead of arrays or constants or any of the other options.

I often look over big name projects code like wordpress, vbulletin, phpbb, and other PHP based applications that are used by many people and can handle a lot of traffic generally.  The results I found were that most of these do not use GETEXT, most of them just do language files with ARRAYS in them.

So I am wanting to know, how can I benchmark the performance of using GETEXT?  Including speed and memory+resources used?

Comment: Not sure why you got a down vote..seems like a valid question..+1

Comment: @Mr-sk thank you, if you saw my previous valid question also you would understand, someone thinks I down voted them on my last question so it's like a game to some people.  Appreciate it though =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Benchmarking PHP Localization – Is gettext fast enough?](http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2006/04/10/benchmarking-php-localization-is-gettext-fast-enough/)

---

[image]

---

> How can I benchmark the performance of using GETEXT? Including speed and memory+resources used?

Using [`microtime(true)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) and [`memory_get_usage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php).

Comment: @jasondavis: Is there anything else you'd want to know? Do you still have any doubts?